# Error when trying to use aliased column name in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my SQL query. I want to select records by debt amount. Amount is counted by relation with two tables.

This works fine:

```
SELECT `i`.*, 
(i.amount_netto + (i.amount_netto * i.vat / 100)) - (SUM(p.amount_netto)) AS `debt`,
`e`.`name` AS `user_name`,
`e`.`surname` AS `user_surname`,
`c`.`name` AS `contractor_name`
FROM `invoices` AS `i` 
INNER JOIN `payments` AS `p` ON i.id = p.invoice_id 
INNER JOIN `employees` AS `e` ON i.employee_id = e.id 
INNER JOIN `contractors` AS `c` ON i.contractor_id = c.id 
GROUP BY `i`.`id` 
ORDER BY `debt` ASC
```

But when I add a WHERE clause by `debt` I get an error:

```
Unknown column 'debt' in 'where clause'
```

Query looks like this:

```
SELECT `i`.*, 
(i.amount_netto + (i.amount_netto * i.vat / 100)) - (SUM(p.amount_netto)) AS `debt`, 
`e`.`name` AS `user_name`,
`e`.`surname` AS `user_surname`,
`c`.`name` AS `contractor_name`
FROM `invoices` AS `i` 
INNER JOIN `payments` AS `p` ON i.id = p.invoice_id 
INNER JOIN `employees` AS `e` ON i.employee_id = e.id 
INNER JOIN `contractors` AS `c` ON i.contractor_id = c.id 
WHERE `debt` > 1 
GROUP BY `i`.`id` 
ORDER BY `debt` ASC
```

Why I can't access `debt` in the WHERE clause, but I can in the ORDER clause?

Comment: you should use the table alias to access debt, it could be `p.debt` may be or other aliases you made.

Comment: I tried to use p.debt and there is no reaction. Still i have an error: "Unknown column 'p.debt' in 'where clause''"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`debt` is not a column, but an *alias*. Column (expression) aliases are not resolved until after the query is executed, therefore they cannot be used in WHERE clauses.

For example this query is not legal:

```
select foo + 3 as bar
from baz
where bar = 39
```

And instead you have to rewrite the whole expression in the WHERE clause:

```
select foo + 3 as bar
from baz
where foo + 3 = 39
```

---

Furthermore, since `debt` is actually based on an aggregate, you cannot filter this in a WHERE clause. You must instead use HAVING to evaluate the predicate *after the aggregation*. Therefore your query should be:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY ...
HAVING (i.amount_netto + (i.amount_netto * i.vat / 100)) - (SUM(p.amount_netto)) > 1
ORDER BY ...
```

Note that [MySql offers an SQL extension which enables the use of aliases in the HAVING clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50391/why-does-mysql-allow-having-to-use-select-aliases), so you can also do:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY ...
HAVING debt > 1
ORDER BY ...
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL doesn't typically allow you to reference column aliases in WHERE, GROUP BY or HAVING clauses. MySQL does support referencing column aliases in the GROUP BY and HAVING

try change your where query to

```
WHERE (i.amount_netto + (i.amount_netto * i.vat / 100)) - (SUM(p.amount_netto)) > 1 GROUP BY i.id ORDER BY debt ASC
```

another option, you could use a subquery

```
SELECT * from (`i`.*, (i.amount_netto + (i.amount_netto * i.vat / 100)) - (SUM(p.amount_netto)) AS `debt`, `e`.`name` AS `user_name`, `e`.`surname` AS `user_surname`, `c`.`name` AS `contractor_name` FROM `invoices` AS `i` INNER JOIN `payments` AS `p` ON i.id = p.invoice_id INNER JOIN `employees` AS `e` ON i.employee_id = e.id INNER JOIN `contractors` AS `c` ON i.contractor_id = c.id  GROUP BY `i`.`id`) as newTable
WHERE `debt` > 1 ORDER BY `debt` ASC
```

Comment: SELECT `i`.*, (i.amount_netto + (i.amount_netto * i.vat / 100)) - (SUM(p.amount_netto)) AS `debt`, `e`.`name` AS `user_name`, `e`.`surname` AS `user_surname`, `c`.`name` AS `contractor_name` FROM `invoices` AS `i` INNER JOIN `payments` AS `p` ON i.id = p.invoice_id INNER JOIN `employees` AS `e` ON i.employee_id = e.id INNER JOIN `contractors` AS `c` ON i.contractor_id = c.id WHERE (i.amount_netto + (i.amount_netto * i.vat / 100)) - (SUM(p.amount_netto)) > 1 GROUP BY i.id ORDER BY debt ASC; I have an error about invalid use of group function.

Comment: ah sorry... miss that you use grouping in here... try use the solution propose by lc or you can try using the subquery